# Selenium Page Objects: Why should I return this?

Tags: selenium, pageobjects, page-factory

Reading [SeleniumHQ's pageobject documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) they specify examples of returning "this" from methods that do not navigate to other pages. My question is why?

I thought maybe the state of the page object could be a reason, however the page itself (the actual UI page) may change state or refresh but the page object itself would not. [Page Factory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) with its @FindBy annotations already ensure that each WebElement will be found every time it is called, so the state of the elements doesn't seem to be relevant this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider their example

```
public LoginPage typeUsername(String username) {
    driver.findElement(usernameLocator).sendKeys(username);
    return this;    
}

public LoginPage typePassword(String password) {
    driver.findElement(passwordLocator).sendKeys(password);
    return this;    
}

public HomePage submitLogin() {
    driver.findElement(loginButtonLocator).submit();
    return new HomePage(driver);    
}
```

now assume we have create the page object create as `page`. If you didn't return anything your code would like

```
page.typeUsername("tarun");
page.typePassword("lalwani");
HomePage newPage = page.submitLogin()
```

But when you return this, it allows you to do method chaining. So I can use it like below

```
HomePage newPage = page.typeUsername("tarun").typePassword("lalwani").submitLogin()
```

As you can see it will save you some coding effort and much more elegant with IDE intellisense

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the examples. This actually makes sense. There's no consequence in adding it and it provides new options to save some code on the implementation/test side.

Answer (score 0):

It allows method chaining, as demonstrated in Tarun's answer, but it also captures flow. If logging in from the Login Page routes you to the Home Page, then your login method would return a Home Page page object. If that flow ever changed, you would update your login method to return some other page object and it would cause errors in the IDE everywhere that the flow would fail. It helps you find the places you need to fix faster.

Having said that, I don't return page objects in my methods. I'm not a big fan of method chaining for page objects. I think it obscures the test flow because you can lose track of which page you are on by chaining too many methods together.

By returning page objects, you also have to write extra methods for error cases, etc. You can see this in their example. There is a `submitLogin()` method that returns a Home Page and a `submitLoginExpectingFailure()` that returns a Login Page and so on. For me, I haven't found the benefits to outweigh the extra code and difficulty reading the test flow.